# Using inner `[(ngModel)]` for a generic control?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an independant `hello` component  - which contains an `Input`

```
<input type='text' [(ngModel)]='innerValue'   />
```

All this component is doing ( for question simplification ) is to add a red border

(This component is being used in many places throughout the App.)

But if I use it like  :

```
<hello     [(ngModel)]="v1.a" ></hello>

 {{v1 | json}}
```

Where :

```
 public v1 ={a:'123'};
```

Then initially it has the same value :

[image]

But if I change the input value - I don't see the value reflected :

[image]

I know that I can pass the whole object `v1` and to use `v1.a` in the home component but I want to use that textbox  in many places where it's not always ngModeled to `v1.a`

So in Banana  component it should be :

```
<hello  type='text' [(ngModel)]='myBanana.name'   />
```

And in Apple component it should be:

```
<hello  type='text' [(ngModel)]='myapple.color'   />
```

**Question:**

How can I make the home component to "support" any ngModel values and update the outside model ?

[**online demo 1**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-controlvalueeaccessor-with-validator-the-right-w-a5hgrh?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this line:

```
<input type='text' [(ngModel)]="innerValue" />
```

To this:

```
<input type='text' (ngModelChange)='onChangeCallback($event)' [ngModel]="innerValue"  />
```

If you're implementing `ControlValueAccessor` you need to invoke `onChangeCallback` any time the internal component state changes.

Working forked [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-controlvalueeaccessor-with-validator-the-right-w-5d5sg9)