# Accessing component properties from another component

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and trying to implement a custom material datepicker component (one that only allows month and year selection) and am having trouble accessing its value from a separate component.  I modified one of the examples from https://v7.material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview and am trying to use the suggestions from this particular stackoverflow post/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50723598 (Angular 7+ section).

Here's my month-year-datepicker.component.html:

```
<mat-form-field class="reporting-datepicker">
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" [(ngModel)]="inputValue" (ngModelChange)="inputValueChange.emit(inputDPValue)" [min]="minDate">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dp
                  [startView]="viewMode"
                  (yearSelected)="chosenYearHandler($event, dp)"
                  (monthSelected)="chosenMonthHandler($event, dp)"
                  panelClass="">
  </mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here's my month-year-datepicker.component.ts (the relevant parts):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'month-year-datepicker',
  templateUrl: 'month-year-datepicker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['month-year-datepicker.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS}
  ],
})

export class MonthYearDatepicker {
  viewMode: string = "year";
  minDate: Moment;

  @Input() yearOnly: boolean = false;
  @Input() inputValue: Moment;
  @Output() inputValueChange: EventEmitter<Moment> = new EventEmitter<Moment>();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.yearOnly)
      this.viewMode = "multi-year"
    this.minDate = moment().subtract(5, 'months');
  }  

  chosenYearHandler(normalizedYear: Moment, datepicker: MatDatepicker<Moment>) {
    var ctrlValue = moment(this.inputValue);
    ctrlValue.year(normalizedYear.year());
    this.inputValue = ctrlValue;
    if (this.yearOnly) datepicker.close();
  }

  chosenMonthHandler(normalizedMonth: Moment, datepicker: MatDatepicker<Moment>) {
    var ctrlValue = moment(this.inputValue);
    ctrlValue.month(normalizedMonth.month());
    this.inputValue = ctrlValue;
    datepicker.close();
  }
}
```

And then, in my separate reporting.component.html file, I am adding the datepicker like:

```
<month-year-datepicker [yearOnly]="false" [(inputValue)]="datepickerValue" ngDefaultControl></month-year-datepicker>
```

However, in my separate reporting.component.ts file (simplified), I cannot access the value of `datepickerValue`:

```
export class ReportingComponent extends ComponentBase implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  datepickerValue: Date;

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(){}

  getDate() {
    return this.datepickerValue; // <- this is undefined still
  }
```

}

I'm obviously missing something or misunderstanding how the binding works between components and would greatly appreciate any help!  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to subscribe to the inputValueChange event from inside the MonthYearDatepicker component, to see if the event fires?

Answer (score 0):

Update

```
(ngModelChange)="inputValueChange.emit(inputDPValue)"
```

to

```
(ngModelChange)="inputValueChange.emit($event)"
```

---

Also update this typo `[(ngModel)]="inputValue"` to `[ngModel]="inputValue"` since you're already also using the `(ngModelChange)` syntax. It's unlikely to be breaking anything, but you should use one syntax or the other, not both.