# How to pass ngForm to child component?

Tags: angular

I have a custom input component that I want to reuse in several forms. But how can I pass the parent's form context to it? I already managed to do this with reactive forms by passing the `FormGroup` instance and the name of the field. I'm trying to achieve the same with template driven forms but I had no success so far. This is my code:

```html
<!-- parent.component.html -->
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="console.log(JSON.stringify(f.value))">
  <input name="someField" ngModel />
  <app-child name="myField"></app-child>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```html
<!-- child.component.html -->
<input ngModel [name]="name" />
```

```
// child.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css'],
})
class ChildComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

The binding didn't went right, since when the form is submitted `f.value.myField` is not defined, only `f.value.someField`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngModelGroup` directive then provide it in your child component like below and here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2unhqh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) :

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="console.log(JSON.stringify(f.value))">
  <input name="someField" ngModel />
  <app-child ngModelGroup="myField"></app-child> // here
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
// child.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css'],
  viewProviders: [{provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgModelGroup}] // here
})
class ChildComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... when I do so, `f.value.myField` evaluates to `{}` instead of undefined. That's a start. The editor also complains with `"No provider for ControlContainer"` (in `parent.component.html`), but the code runs fine.

Comment: give me a few minutes i'll post a working stackblitz

Comment: No hurries, my work day is already over . Thanks in advance!

Comment: i added the link in the answer

Comment: It works. Thank you! However, it isn't quite what I was looking for. This one fits my needs better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618050/how-to-create-custom-input-component-with-ngmodel-working-in-angular-6/50723598